# "Cannot run C compiled programs" error when installing PDO PHP module

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I have a cPanel server I want to install some packages on. I connected to the server as root and ran the following commands to update and delete all the existing repositories:

```
yum update
yum clean all
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

My last command was to install the PDO PHP module, but that's when I got an error:

```
root@linux [~/TMP]# pecl install pdo
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"
downloading PDO-1.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PDO-1.0.3.tgz (52,613 bytes)
.............done: 52,613 bytes
12 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/PDO-1.0.3
running: /root/tmp/pear/PDO/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-root/PDO-1.0.3':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/PDO/configure' failed
root@linux [~/TMP]# pecl install bdoNo releases available for package "pecl.php.net/bdo"
install failed
```

What causes this error? How can I fix it?

---

**Edit**: Also, when I run `yum install php*`, after checking dependencies I get this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rrdtool-php-1.3.8-6.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
```

---

**Edit**: I uploaded my [config.log](http://pastebin.com/3MRNQJdk) and [config.status](http://pastebin.com/tES5MeHb) files

Comment: Upload (e.g. to http://pastebin.com) the full contents of `config.log` and `config.status`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install packages containing development tools required for compilation. You can install them one-by-one :

```
yum install gcc
yum install make
...
yum install glibc-devel
```

*Or* you can install in one command a lot of them :

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://blog.ntrippy.net/2008/06/installing-peclpear-php-modules-on-rhel.html) seems to have an answer.

I did not have cc installed, and installed gcc, that worked for me.

```
yum install gcc
pecl install pdo
```